# ELF modify section flags

Tags: gcc, gdb, readelf

I compiled a C code using gcc and when I check the sections of the ELF using readelf I can see that the flags for .data section are set to WA (Writable and Allocatable).

Is it possible to modify these flags? Can I make this section executable?

I am using gdb to debug this binary and I would like to set the flags for .data section as Executable at a certain point. So, can this be done using either gdb or gcc?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to modify these flags? Can I make this section executable?

Yes. If you want to do this as a one-off, the simplest approach may be to compile source to assembly, and modify section attributes there, then compile assembly into object file and link as usual.

> I am using gdb to debug this binary and I would like to set the flags for .data section as Executable at a certain point.

You also could call `mprotect(addr, len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC)` from within GDB.

Note: modifying the flags in the `.data` section after the binary has been linked will have no effect whatsoever: the kernel *doesn't* look at sections, only at `PT_LOAD` *segments*.

> how to mark the data section as executable in the assembly code? I think, something like this: .section .data,"awx",@progbits.

Yes, that looks correct. Did it not work?

> mprotect() not found

Is your executable statically linked? If not, `mprotect` should be found (in `libc.so`), and you possibly have a GDB bug. It may help to nudge GDB into finding `mprotect` if you `print &mprotect` first.

Also note: `mprotect(0x0804a020, 80, PROT_READ, PROT_WRITE, PROT_EXEC)` is very different from what I suggested (`mprotect` takes 3 parameters, not 5). You also need to read `man mprotect` carefully -- it requires start address to be page-aligned.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell with an example about how to mark the data section as executable in the assembly code? I think, something like this: .section .data,"awx",@progbits. Also, I tried using the mprotect call within gdb (while debugging the main() subroutine in binary) like this: mprotect(0x0804a020, 80, PROT_READ, PROT_WRITE, PROT_EXEC) and it says, mprotect() not found.